# Multiple output data set for neural network

Tags: neural-network, artificial-intelligence, classification, prediction

I've developed an Artificial Neural Network in C++ for an assignment and I was wondering if anyone knew of any multiple output data sets that I could use to test my network? I'm trying to prove that a modification I've done causes the network to perform better with a wide range of data sets.

I've tried a few sites but none of them state the number of outputs leading me to assume that they all have one output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UCI](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets.html) machine learning repository currently maintain 235 data sets as a service to the machine learning community.

A large percentage of them contains multiple types of labels, e.g.,

- [Human Activity Recognition Using Smartphones Data Set](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Human+Activity+Recognition+Using+Smartphones) : Contains 6 output labels:

> ```
> WALKING, WALKING_UPSTAIRS, WALKING_DOWNSTAIRS, SITTING, STANDING, LAYING
> ```

- [Car Evaluation Data Set](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Car+Evaluation): class values include

> ```
> unacc, acc, good, vgood
> ```

Comment: These are just one output column though aren't they? They don't seem to be multiple outputs?

What I'm looking for is more like (to use an abstract example) a data set for food were it outputs what food group it is and how healthy it is (so more than one neuron on the output layer)

Comment: You are right. Usually those datasets have only one output column which could be multi-valued. However, you are not limited to only use their class variable. Say, the current system is `(x1,x2,x3)-> y`, where `xi` are attributes and `y` is the label, you can just treat it as `(x1,x2)`->(x3,y). In the `Car evaluation dataset`, `price of maintenance ` could be a possible output, right?

Answer (score 0):

MNIST is a standard 10-class dataset of 20x20 pixel images of handwritten digits (0 - 9).  You can find the dataset (along with performance results from various classifiers, including neural nets) at http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/